# Dynamodb for date range queries

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I am creating an application for storing all the people information who are having some subscription for some period. The data I am storing in the dynamodb table is:

> 1. personId
> 2. beginDate
> 3. EndDate

Now, I wanted to write queries like

> 1. get all the persons who are active during some period(between date1 and date2)
> 2. get all the persons who are active on a particular date.

Since, I am using the dynamodb table, I am thinking the best way to do this to have global hash key on begin and enddate and store the timestamp of begin and end date.

Does this make sense? Or is there a better way to do this in Dynamodb?

Comment: For query 1, are you looking for active durations that are entirely contained in the search period or active durations that overlap the search period at all?

Comment: For 1st one, I am looking for overlap ones.

Comment: Can a person have more than one begin and end date?

Comment: Also, how granular are your dates? Are they just dates, or are they full timestamps?

Comment: Full timestamps. Till seconds level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your design seems correct.
You would need 2 GSI's:

1. Hash_key on begin and Range_key on end.
2. hash_key on end and range_key on begin

For **query 1**, you would need to query on GS1 with

1. begin between date1 and date2 (use GSI1)
2. end between date1 and date2 (use GSI2)
3. begin before date1 (GSI1) and end after date2 (GSI2) and take intersection of list

**query 2** is same as query 1 only where begin date is first second of date and end date is last second of date.

Comment: let me know if you need example

Comment: I'm interested in learning more about how this works... 

Comment: Ah, I get it now. Step 3 is going to be really expensive though 